# Magento 2 remove shipping and payment method step

Tags: magento2, checkout

I need to remove shipping and payment method from checkout because in a site client don't want payment and shipping method.

I used this link [Remove Payment Method - Magento 2](http://blog.mageworx.com/2016/08/an-easy-way-to-remove-a-payment-method-in-magento-2/)

How I can achieve it in Magento 2.?

Comment: Do you want to removal all shipping and payment methods or specific ones?

Comment: Nope I want to remove all

Comment: I just want to remove payment and shipping steps from checkout process.